# Rhythmbox duplicating songs in playlists

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox, ipod

I am using an ipod Classic 5th gen with Rhythmbox and it seems whenever you make a playlist or add songs to an existing playlist it just duplicates the songs everytime you add a new one. So many of my playlists have like 9 duplicates of every song! Is there a way to fix this?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: well it doesnt happen for me. What version of rhythmbox are you using?

Comment: Every time I change the settings all songs are readded to rb database. 0.12.8

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be because the Rythmbox's Plug-ins for iPod (I mean Copyright 2006, but I don't known the new versions), make sure that is not selected / activated.

It's just disable the plug-in for iPod and the problem stops, how even is possible to use the iPod with general players (MTP), the iPod will work just to put the songs there, not for playlist and every time your iPod will be song's recount! I know that it's not good! But, your playlists will be saved of the duplicate problems.

A tip, you can use the gtkPod. ;)